# Как в Linux сделать цикл для диапазона строк?

Tags: linux, bash, циклы

Есть такой скрипт. Как можно сделать это все в цикле?
Файл test.txt может содержать больше 100 строк.

```
cat test1.txt | sed -n 1,5p | jq -Rn \
    --arg v1 / \
    --arg v3 server1 \
    '[inputs] | map({"{#NAME}" : $v1, "{#LIST}": ., "{#MARK}": $v3}) | { "data": . }'

cat test1.txt | sed -n 6,11p  | jq -Rn \
    --arg v1 / \
    --arg v3 server1 \
    '[inputs] | map({"{#NAME}" : $v1, "{#LIST}": ., "{#MARK}": $v3}) | { "data": . }'

cat test1.txt | sed -n 12,17p  | jq -Rn \
    --arg v1 / \
    --arg v3 server1 \
    '[inputs] | map({"{#NAME}" : $v1, "{#LIST}": ., "{#MARK}": $v3}) | { "data": . }'
```

Comment: Цикл вам показали в вашем предыдущем вопросе, там только добавить пару переменных для вычисления начальной/конечной строки и можно помещать в него cat / sed

Comment: ну и возможно предварительно с помощью wc определить количество строк в файле что бы понимать сколько раз циклу работать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поставил комментарии по набору команд, стоит то что в пунктах либо изменяемое
Для изменения количество обрабатываемых строк стоит изменить переменную `step`

```bsh
#Объявляем файл с которым будем работать
file_data=./test1.txt
#Устанавливаем шаг по сколько строк выводим
step=10 
#Переменная начала строки
oldi=1
#Просто генератор итераций цикла
counter=0
#Максимальная строка, после которой останавливаем выполнение
max_line=`wc -l < ${file_data}`
#Начало цикла
for ((i=$step;i<=$(($max_line+$step));i=i+$step)); do
#Повышаем генератор работы цикла
counter=$((counter+1))
```

---

Либо:

```bsh
#Выводим по 10 строк добавляя в начала текст и номер итерации цикла
sed -n ${oldi},${i}p $file_data | sed "s/^/TEST${counter}: /"
```

---

Либо:

```bsh
#Передаем партию строк на обработку в данном случае jq
sed -n ${oldi},${i}p $file_data | jq -Rn \
    --arg v1 / \
    --arg v3 server1 \
    '[inputs] | map({"{#NAME}" : $v1, "{#LIST}": ., "{#MARK}": $v3}) | { "data": . }'
```

---

```bsh
#запоминаем строку с которой начнется следующий вывод
oldi=$(($i+1))
done
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за скрипт.  Один момент только. Если в файле test1.txt 21 строка, например, то будет 2 блока по 10, а последней - 21 строки не будет.

Comment: @perrfect, да действительно такое поведение было, сейчас поправил строку `for ((i=$step;i<=$(($max_line+$step));i=i+$step)); do` попробуйте еще раз

Comment: Да, все работает. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: А если прописать с использованием `seq ...`?

Comment: @0andriy, seq возможно использовать, но это будет просто использование seq, видимых плюсов я не вижу от этого, если они есть, то расскажите об этом.